# Can I cross to Niagara Falls Canada with two months remaining on passport?

Tags: passports, canada

Can I cross by foot to Niagara Falls Canada with slightly less than two months remaining before expiry of my U.S. passport?

One site mentions a six-month expiry remaining requirement, but unclear if this applies to land crossing e.g. Rainbow Bridge. Last time there they did not even stamp the passport so it seems different procedure is followed.

Answer (score 1):

Canada [does not even require US citizens to *have* a passport to enter Canada](https://travel.gc.ca/returning/travelling-to-canada), so there's no way they'd care about the expiration date of the passport you do have.

From the site linked above (emphasis added):

> Non-Canadians entering Canada
>
> When you enter Canada, a Canada Border Services Agency officer may ask to see your passport and a valid visa, if you need one. **If you are a citizen of the United States, you do not need a passport to enter Canada,** but you should carry proof of your citizenship, such as a birth certificate, certificate of citizenship or naturalization, as well as photo identification

Comment: "but you should carry proof of your citizenship" A passport does suffice for citizenship and identification. Would be easier to carry vs a driver's license **and** something else.

Comment: @Michael of course.  But it's clear that they won't require the passport to be valid for and specific length of time.